# Change Display Name of an AudioUnit extension

Tags: ios, audiounit, auv3

How can one change the Display Name of an iOS AudioUnit extension? I built my project with Xcode 11.1 and am running it on iOS 13.

What I have already tried :

In the General tab of the target, change the Display Name value.

In the info.plist of the AudioUnit extension, change the value of :

- Bundle display name
- Bundle name
- description (in AudioComponents[0])

The name appearing in apps like AudioBus and AUM is still the target name, not the display name.